# How to set the links in a text block clickable in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a text box contain links .the contents in the text are generated during run time.My problem is that the links inside the text is not clickable,how can make all links inside the text block  clickable so that when i tap a link it should open the web browser.In android we can set it by using autolink.Is such option is available in wp7 or in wp7.1 mango?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Pure Text</Run>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding HyperLinkTapped}">http://google.com</Hyperlink>
    <Run>Pure Text Again</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

This is supported from Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango).

You can create your own FlowDocument from the your data, at runtime, if necessary.

Example on how to generate a FlowDocument from a string:

```
private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
{
    var textBlock = new RichTextBox()
    {
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        IsReadOnly = true,
    };

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();

    var runs = new List<Inline>();

    foreach (var word in message.Split(' '))
    {
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) ||
           (word.StartsWith("www.") && Uri.TryCreate("http://" + word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)))
        {
            var link = new Hyperlink();
            link.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
            link.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var hyperLink = (sender as Hyperlink);
                new WebBrowserTask() { Uri = uri }.Show();
            };

            runs.Add(link);
        }
        else
        {
            runs.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
        }

        runs.Add(new Run() { Text = " "});
    }

    foreach (var run in runs)
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);

    textBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

    MessagesListBox.Children.Add(textBlock);
    MessagesListBox.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Comment: I am using 7.1, and this xaml does not even compile for me.

Comment: First, it should be `Hyperlink`, `l` is lower case. Second, I can't get the xaml code to compile in a 7.1 project...

Comment: UPDATE: same code works fine in WPF but neither in Silverlight 5 nor WP7.1.

Comment: XAML sample is incorrect. Hyperlink could be used only within RichTextBox in WP7.

Comment: The documentation you quoted states: "You can use the Hyperlink element to display hyperlinks in a RichTextBox." Can you explain out how you got this code to compile? It won't build for me, in a 7.1 project.

Comment: Plus, your C# example code uses a RichTextBox, while your Xaml uses a TextBlock...

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in functionality to do this.

If your text (including the links) is HTML you could display it in a WebBrowser control.
If not you'll need to parse the text and build the links yourself. (A combination of TextBlocks and HyperlinkButtons inside a WrapPanel is probably the way to go for this.)

Comment: No reason to use HyperlinkButton anymore ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In silverlight RichTextBox contol can help you.

```xml
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="This have to navigate me to Google: "/>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://google.com" TargetName="_blank">google.com</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```