# How do I make links in text clickable in my Twitter application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, hyperlink

I am trying to develop a basic anonymous twitter app the problem i have is i would like to be able to click the content ie. images etc. posted by the tweeter. i would also like to be able to expand the profile picture if possible.

Comment: We're going to need a little more information about what you already have, please be more concrete...

Comment: i followed this guide http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx to make a basic app that displays tweets from a desired user. in the list box of retrieved tweets sometimes will have a link for example twittpic etc.. i would like to be able to click on the twittpic link to view the picture and also click on the users profile picture to enlarge it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To have links in your text you'll need to manipulate the received data at run-time. Such that you no longer fill the textblock with pure text but that you actually change the links into hyperlinks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7567840/47064) handles that in detail:

```
private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
{
    var textBlock = new RichTextBox()
    {
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        IsReadOnly = true,
    };

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();

    var runs = new List<Inline>();

    foreach (var word in message.Split(' '))
    {
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) ||
           (word.StartsWith("www.") && Uri.TryCreate("http://" + word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)))
        {
            var link = new Hyperlink();
            link.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
            link.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var hyperLink = (sender as Hyperlink);
                new WebBrowserTask() { Uri = uri }.Show();
            };

            runs.Add(link);
        }
        else
        {
            runs.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
        }

        runs.Add(new Run() { Text = " "});
    }

    foreach (var run in runs)
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);

    textBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

    MessagesListBox.Children.Add(textBlock);
    MessagesListBox.UpdateLayout();
}
```

The downside of the above code is that you lose the data binding. You could try to change the function in such way that it changes the existing text blocks instead of adding new ones. Only keep your data context if you keep to later use the tweets in your own application rather than just creating links.

It kind of takes getting used to dynamically manipulating the XAML.

**Update:** Actually, I found that you could bind [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) of any element that supports it to an UIElement. So you could for instance change the TextBox line to a useless container `<StackPanel  Content="{Binding MyRichText}"></StackPanel>` and assign your `textBlock` from the above code to the `MyRichText` property of your `TwitterItem`...

---

To make the image clickable you'll need a [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton(v=vs.95).aspx). Just change your template:

```
<HyperlinkButton>
  singleObject
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Which means that you can simply surround your image object.

Note that the HyperlinkButton has a [NavigateURI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton.navigateuri(v=vs.95).aspx) property, so you simply bind that to the image of the URL (or the profile page of the author, or ...).

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateURI="{Binding ImageSource}">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Something like that. For example, if you want a profile URL instead you'll need to change the `NavigateURI="{Binding ImageSource}` to `NavigateURI="{Binding ProfileURL}"` and then you add a ProfileURL to your TwitterItem and set it to an URL where you create the new twitter items.

So, this is a more simple change.