# How can i set autolink for phone number, email id and urls in textblock text

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new in windows phone development. Please tell me is there is any option to highlight the phone number, email id and url links. And also want to set auto link. I have a textblock that contains description ( ex:- email id, phone number and some text ). I want to set auto link property..please tell me is it possible in windows phone 7? or is there any ways to set auto link for email id?

Comment: what do you mean by 'autolink'? is it hyperlink ?

Comment: yes, it is hyperlink. In android, there is direct property called autolink that is used to highlight phone number and email id. when we click on phone Number then it will give option to call and when we click on email id link then it will give option to mail. so i want to know there is any property in windows phone 7 so that i can highlight phone number and email id with blue color and when we click on that then it gives option to call on that number and mail on that mail id. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem by combining these following links data :-

[How to set the links in a text block clickable in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567600/how-to-set-the-links-in-a-text-block-clickable-in-wp7)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandwindowsphone7trainingcourse_addinglauncherstoemailandphonenumberslab_topic2.aspx

I think it is helpful for developers to set autolink (option to call on phone number and mail on mail id ).

Answer (score 0):

Although only discussing URLs, this question should be a starting point:

[How to set the links in a text block clickable in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567600/how-to-set-the-links-in-a-text-block-clickable-in-wp7)

Unfortunately there is no built-in autolink functionality.

Comment: Thanks..above link is helpful for me to set hyperlink in a large text..Thanks alot..